# vue 3 | load custom svg file to veutify (load svg as inline data)

Tags: vue.js, svg, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I wish to find a way to easily use custom svg files in vuetify components.
When i work with Material Design Icons, I can easily do this and everything works fine:

```
<v-btn :icon="mdiSync"></v-btn>
```

but when I'm using custom svg I need to do:

```
 <!-- actually here the :icon is not necessary, it's just to get the style -->
 <v-btn :icon='true'>
          <v-icon>
            <img :src='ZnAzureIconSvg' />
          </v-icon>
 </v-btn>
```

the difference between them is that mdi is inline data while my icons are just file paths:

```
console.log(ZnAzureIconSvg) // "/src/assets/login/azure.svg"
console.log(ZnAzureIconSvg) // "M12,18A6,6 0 0,1 6,12C6,11 6.25,10.03 6.7,9.2L5.24,7.74C4.46,8.97 4,10.43 4,12A8,8 0 0,0 12,20V23L16,19L12,15M12,4V1L8,5L12,9V6A6,6 0 0,1 18,12C18,13 17.75,13.97 17.3,14.8L18.76,16.26C19.54,15.03 20,13.57 20,12A8,8 0 0,0 12,4Z VM1421"
```

how can I can **conveniently** import svg and use them as inline data?

my vue and vuetify versions:

> ```
> "vuetify": "^3.1.15",
> "vue": "^3.2.47",
> ```

Comment: Take inspiration from the Native JavaScript [``<load-file>`` Web Component](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd) I blogged about.